# Remove whitespace from HTML django template response

Tags: python, django

My assert statement is

```
self.assertContains(request, 'User Available\n  Restaurant')
```

The `print(request)` returns

`<TemplateResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">`

And the `print(request.content)` contains

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">User Available\n Restaurant </button>\n \n\n </td>\n\n
```

The problem is there is "double space" instead of "single space" in the `print(request.content)`, therefore in an attempt to strip the spaces of the HTML response for a more robust testing. I did;

```
html_page = str(request.content)
html_page.replace(" ", "")
self.assertContains(html_page, 'User Available\nRestaurant')
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'status_code'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with HTML responses, you should add `html=True`.

```
self.assertContains(request, 'User Available\n  Restaurant', html=True)
```

That will solve your whitespace problem. Also, the text should be a valid HTML or it will raise an error (notice `</td>` at the end).

Answer (score 0):

there is a trick to remove the non HTML synthax:

1. first you do the queryset:
2. second you create the template response
3. you render it
4. you return the readable version

   ```
   qs = YourModel.object.filter(param=this)
   t = TemplateResponse(request, 'template.html', {'queryset': qs})
   t = t.render()
   t = t.rendered_content
   return mark_safe(t)
   ```